# dataTable inside tabView does not scroll properly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Currently, I have a `DataTable` inside a `TabView`.

It works fine when I first load the page when the table is empty.  However, when I load the table after processing data using a `CommandButton`, the column header does not scroll along with rest of the table horizontally.

The application is on PrimeFaces 3.5.  Following is the code that the application has.

```
<p:panel id="panDep">
  <p:tabView id="depRpt" widgetVar="depRpt">
    <p:tab title="Detail Report" id="detailRpt">
      <p:treeTable id="dataList" >
        ...
        ...
      </p:treeTable>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Summary Report" id="summaryRpt">
      <p:dataTable id="sumRpt" value="#{dep.lstSummary}"
        scrollHeight="315" var="s" scrollable="true" rowIndexVar="rowsn">
        ...
        ...
      </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
</p:panel>
```

**Edit:**
For some reason, it works fine for the first tab but not for the second tab.  Whichever table I put on the first tab, the scrolling works, but not for the second tab.

Comment: Please add what you try so far to see if there's something wrong.

Comment: And did you try newer versions?